# Angular 2 http.put - Cannot read property 'atualizaStatus' of undefined

Tags: rest, angular, angular2-services

I'm trying to update a field on my application using the put method however I'm having some problems trying to do it. I'm new on Angular 2 and still dont know how to do it correctly.

Here is my Service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {DisputaPropostaComponent} from './disputas-proposta.component';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DisputaPropostaService{

    contato:Object[] = [];
    name: string;
    headers:Headers;
    url: string = 'http://localhost:3004/disputas';

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    atualizaStatus (body:any): Observable<DisputaPropostaComponent[]>{
        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(body); // Stringify payload
        let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); // ... Set content type to JSON
        let options       = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
        return this.http.put(`${this.url}/${body['id']}`, body, options)
                         .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Ocorreu um erro em nosso servidor, tente novamente mais tarde')); //...errors if any
    }   
}
```

and here is the Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {DisputaComponent} from '../../disputas/disputas.component';
import {DisputaService} from '../../disputas/disputas.service';
import {DisputaPropostaService} from './disputas-proposta.service';
import {disputaPropostas} from './proposta.interface';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'detalhes',
  templateUrl: `disputas-proposta.component.html`,
  providers: [DisputaPropostaService]
})

export class DisputaPropostaComponent  {

    disputa: DisputaComponent;
    service: DisputaService;
    propostaService:DisputaPropostaService;
    route: ActivatedRoute;
    inputProposta = false;
    proposta:disputaPropostas = {proposta_usuario: null, proposta_cliente: null}

    constructor(service: DisputaService, route:ActivatedRoute, propostaService:DisputaPropostaService){
    // Some other code here...
    }

    recusaProposta(){
      if (this.disputa.propostas_realizadas == 0){
        this.propostaService.atualizaStatus(this.disputa)
          .subscribe(
            res => console.log(res),
            error=> console.log(error)
          );
      }
      this.inputProposta = true;
      this.disputa.propostas_realizadas++;
      if ((this.disputa.propostas_realizadas) == ((this.disputa.maximo_propostas)-1))
        alert("Ultima proposta")
    }
```

The message I'm getting is the following one:

> Cannot read property 'atualizaStatus' of undefined

Am I missing something obvious? Thank you in advance.

P.S.: if someone has an article that explains the REST for Angular 2 I'll be glad to know :)

Comment: // Some other code here... Does this include this.propostaService = propostaService ?

Comment: No, should I put it there? Can you explain why please?

Comment: I am no angular 2 expert but what you are using is dependency injection and you are losing scope of your dependency, in this case propostaService. You can change your constructor to, private propostaService:DisputaPropostaService, and remove propostaService:DisputaPropostaService; from above

Comment: Thank you very much, it really help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to implement dependency injection

Remove

```
service: DisputaService;
propostaService:DisputaPropostaService;
route: ActivatedRoute;
```

Update

```
constructor(private service: DisputaService,private route:ActivatedRoute, private propostaService:DisputaPropostaService){
    // Some other code here...
}
```

Which has the same result as [Bougarfaoui El houcine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42627996/5348487) answer

I found this book to be a lot of help. https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/di/

Comment: Thank you Steven :)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your component constructor

```
 constructor(service: DisputaService, route:ActivatedRoute, propostaService: DisputaPropostaService){
       this.service = service;
       this.route = route;
       this.propostaService = propostaService;
       // ...
    }
```